# staggered map display error in cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to load staggered map, created at Tiled Map Editor. But something goes wrong. Simple isometric map is loaded ok. 
Here's what it look like in Tiled Map Editor:
http://gyazo.com/eb2d5643f03ab453330aa573a7b99f3e

Here is the result of loading this map:
http://gyazo.com/117930a33f4207f74bb5b56979df4eec

Here's how I load the map (and again simple isometric is loaded ok with the very code)

```
-(id) init    
{
    tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"test_tile_map_offset.tmx"];
    background = [tileMap layerNamed:@"Background"];

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d's CCTMXTiledMap class does not support "staggered" (rectangular) isometric tilemaps.

You would have to change the code or write a custom renderer.

Comment: I can not find a thing about cocos2D and staggered isometric tilemaps. Do you have any reference/source for how I can get it to work?

Comment: Like I said it's not supported / not available. You'd have to program it yourself. It mainly involves changing the layout code for the tilemaps. You may find some info on Amit's page, he's got plenty of tilemapping resources perhaps also something about how regular and staggered isometric renderers are implemented. http://www.redblobgames.com